# Excel Line chart X-axis does not display the right date/time

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, date-time, axis

I am trying to plot a line chart in Excel , the x-axis is changing the year value significantly and I cannot figure out why.

It is taking my data from 2017 and adding over 100 years to it.  For the life of my I cannot figure out why.

This is data I manually type in as time `M/DD/YY 13:00`, the same thing happens when I format the data to year.  I am very good with Excel and VBA editor, but this one I cannot figure out.

[image: i]

Comment: Is it your intention to add all the values for the same dates? Or plot all rows seperately? if the latter, just switch the setting to `Text Axis`

Comment: If you can post the source file about this problem, it will be more helpful.

Comment: I don't know why the dates are 100+ years off. Are the Y values plotted in the proper sequence? Also, do you realize that Excel ignores the time part of the date-time in a line chart? It would be helpful to see the data and chart, though we all understand confidentiality.